# Eddington-LeMaitre model

Tags: homework-and-exercises, cosmology, cosmological-constant

I'm trying to solve Friedmann equations for $k=1 $ & $p=0$ (matter).
These are equations:
$$3(\dot{R}^2 +1)/R^2 -λ =8πGε$$
$$(2R\ddot{R}+\dot{R}^2 +1)/R^2 -λ=0$$
If we use $(\dot{R}^2 +1) /R^2$ and put it in the second equation:

$$\ddot{R}+\frac16\omega^2R=0 \\ \omega^2=8πGε-2λ$$

If $\omega^2=0$, then we have Einstein's static model.

Furthermore, for $\omega^2>0$, the solution is like $R=A\exp(\omega t)$ or $R=A\sin(\omega t)+B\cos(\omega t)$ with suitable constants. But I know Eddington-LeMaitre model (expanding universe) and the solution above, it's not that and it doesn't have coasting period or other properties of that model. I don't know what is wrong, can someone help me?

Comment: If you put $(\dot{R}^2 + 1)/R^2$ in the second equation, you get $6\ddot{R}/R + 8\pi G\varepsilon -2\lambda = 0$. So you forgot an $R$ in the denominator.

Comment: ...but that is just a typo. More importantly, $\varepsilon$ (the density) is not a constant, it is a function of $R$.

Comment: oh,I forgot it and ε is a function of R.I use εR^3=alpha.

Comment: Yes, and that means that $\omega$ is not a constant, so the solution you wrote is not correct.